# What's the Spanish expression for 'This is filthy'?

Tags: traducción, expresiones

I posted a answer to a [question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/187869/28275) at drupal.stackexchange.com and a user has left me the following [comment](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/187869/show-node-ids-along-with-titles-in-entityreference-autocomplete-list/187896?noredirect=1#comment227788_187896):

> ... This is filthy!!!

I obtain from google the translation as: "Esto es asqueroso !!!".

However, the user says in another comment that the answer to the question it's fine.

So, What's the Spanish expression for 'This is filthy'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This is filthy" is slang. It can't be translated literally. A great page to look up slang terms is [Urban Dictionary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=filthy). There, filthy is described as:

> A word originating in Seattle meaning dope, tight or cool: *Damn fool, those shoes are filthy*

Now, you're asking for a translation to Spanish. Like most slang words, there will be great differences from a Spanish speaking country to another. Since "filthy" means pretty much the same as cool, it can be translated accordingly. In [this post](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/15670/if-someone-does-something-interesting-i-might-say-that-it-is-cool-how-does-th) there are some examples regarding how to translate "cool" to Spanish. I like *¡Increíble!* for this specific case, although there will unavoidably be considerable nuances lost in translation.

Comment: Gracias, creo comprender un poco ahora el comentario que me realizó el usuario sobre la respuesta que dí.

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer no necesitas tildar *di.*

Comment: @Ustanak gracias, pero ya no puedo editar el comentario, no me percate al escribir. Pudiera explicarme a que se refiere con hacer trampa en el comentario de su respuesta, no pude comprender el significado.

Answer (score 2):

### Seattle, Washington - ¡Qué padre!

**This is filthy** isn't something that I've ever known or heard to mean *this is cool*, *this is awesome*, etcetera.  But, in Seattle, WA, somehow or another, they developed the slang --- This is filthy.  It's used to express **envy**.

> That hat is filthy! - Means the hat is very nice/awesome

In other regions of the US, they have even more odd choices of adjectives to use, like:

> This is **tight**
>
> This is **sweet**
>
> This is **dope**
>
> This is **badass**

---

Possible Spanish equivalents

> - ¡Qué padre!
> - ¡Qué chido!
> - ¡Qué copado!

Answer (score 1):

In Argentina, we'd say, ¡Qué mugre!, meaning "What filth!"

I think that might be strong enough to express the concept.

Check out more here: [at Wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=mugre)

I love that site because not only do they detail different countries, but there are often entries in the forum if you scroll down that give you an even better idea through users' questions and answers.

Answer (score 1):

Si en argentina decis: ¡Qué padre! ¡Qué chido! ¡Qué copado! se van a dar cuenta que no sos argentino, esos términos no se usan.
Al ser una expresión cambia según el pais en el que te encuentres, latinoamérica varia mucho en ese sentido, cada pais tiene expresiones propias.
 Filthy en el caso de argentina se diria que asco, que sucio, que mugre